# set Array To RadioButton

Tags: android, arrays

i m trying to Display array to RadioButton. But it is not working , No error is showing in Log cat, Please Help me to get the Array to Radiobuttons

> **Updated Code**

```html
 int count = radioAnsGroup.getChildCount();
 ArrayList<RadioButton> listOfRadioButtons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
      
 for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
  View o = radioAnsGroup.getChildAt(i);
  if (o instanceof RadioButton) {
  listOfRadioButtons.add((RadioButton)o);
 }
```

> **Updated Code**

Help will be appreciate , thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you debuged that code? Are you sure that only three radio button objects are the childs of the group? Why not creating new radio button objects and attach them to the group?

Comment: @rmertins i m trying to create a new RadioButtons and Group them, if it will not work then i will let you know

Comment: Leaf the group in the layout. get it by findViewById and then add new radio buttons for any string in your array.

Comment: When and where in the activity lifecycle are you doing this?

Comment: @ i m doing in OnCreate()

Comment: Ok this is in the main thread and any changes to the UI should be shown after completion of this method.

Comment: @rmertins code updated , now no error is showing in Log cat ,can u  please tell me what m i doing wrong ?

Comment: Now I don't understand your problem anymore. You are now getting the childs and if its a radio button you add it to an array. For what? I thought you want to set the labels of the radio buttons in your view to the values in your string array?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that should work, not tested. For creating radio buttons programaticly, setting the label and placing them in a radio group in your view.

```
String[] labels = new String[3] {"Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3"};

RadioGroup radioAnsGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById("myRadioGroup");

for (String label : lables) {
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
    rb.setText(label);
    radioAnsGroup.addView(rb);
}
```

To do this, the RadioGroup in the Layout needs to be empty. And it will create one RadioButton for an entry in the labels array.

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will help

```
    int count = radioGroup.getChildCount();
    ArrayList<RadioButton> listOfRadioButtons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
        View o = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (o instanceof RadioButton) {
            listOfRadioButtons.add((RadioButton)o);
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"you have "+listOfRadioButtons.size()+" radio buttons");
```

Comment: is array will be 'listOfRadioButtons' add into this Code to show text on RadioButton ?